# How to change Account/Login asp:literal

Tags: asp.net

i default login in asp.net when something in passowrd or username is wrong I have this message : `Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.`

this is some asp:Literal 
How can i change this text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the ASP.NET [Login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx), you can simply set the [FailureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.failuretext.aspx) property to an alternate message.

Or if you need more control, you can template the `Login` control to provide your own custom UI.